# Unity - Zelda life system crashes when updating the hp containers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I built a Zelda health system with 5 health containers. Each container has 4 pieces.

When updating this healthbar, I get an out of range exception.

My code:

```
[SerializeField]
Image[] healthContainers; // 5 containers as images

int currentHealth;
int maxHealth;
int healthPerHealthContainer = 4; // 1 healthcontainer = 4 health pieces

private void Start()
{
    maxHealth = healthContainers.Length * healthPerHealthContainer; // set max hp
    currentHealth = maxHealth; // init current hp
    UpdateHealthBar(); // first gui update
}

public void ChangeHealth(int amount) // get damage or heal
{
    currentHealth = Mathf.Clamp(currentHealth + amount, 0, maxHealth); // add or subtract health
    UpdateHealthBar(); // update gui
}

 public void UpdateHealthBar() // gui updater
{
    int healthContainerIndex = currentHealth / healthPerHealthContainer; // get the current heart to change
    int healthContainerFillAmount = currentHealth % healthPerHealthContainer; // the fillamount of the heart

    if (currentHealth % healthPerHealthContainer == 0)
    {
        if (currentHealth == healthContainers.Length)
        {
            healthContainers[healthContainerIndex - 1].fillAmount = 1;
            return;
        }

        if (healthContainerIndex > 0)
        {
            healthContainers[healthContainerIndex].fillAmount = 0;
            healthContainers[healthContainerIndex - 1].fillAmount = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            healthContainers[healthContainerIndex].fillAmount = 0;
            return;
        }
    }

    healthContainers[healthContainerIndex].fillAmount = healthContainerFillAmount / (float)healthPerHealthContainer;
}
```

So when using 5 health containers by 4 pieces for each health I start with 20 hp. When updating the gui, it crashes on

```
healthContainers[healthContainerIndex].fillAmount = 0;
```

because ..

```
int healthContainerIndex = currentHealth / healthPerHealthContainer;
```

results in

```
healthContainerIndex = 5;
```

and the index range of the array with 5 containers is from 0 to 4.

But simply writing

```
healthContainers[healthContainerIndex -1].fillAmount = 0;
```

is wrong because I need to get the correct heart. So does someone get the mistake I made here? I can't see it..

Comment: I suggest you write down (on a piece of paper) values of `currentHealth` and what you'd expect `healthContainerIndex` to be, and what `healthContainers` indexes you'd expect to change.

Comment: there is almost no reason to use [SerializeField] in Unity.

Comment: @Fattie well writing public ... is not that good. Having the variable on private seems to be more clean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely agree with Jon Skeet on writing it down on a piece of paper, can really help with index problems like this.

That being said, you may want to reconsider if your solution will work the way you want it to or not. The solution that you have only works assuming that the player's health only goes up or down 1 health at a time. If a player gets hit for enough damage or has their health fully restored your solution may skip a step and a heart may not be updated properly. If you just iterate through all of your containers and update them it will be a lot easier to implement and a lot more robust.

```
public void UpdateHealthBar() // gui updater
{
    for (int healthContainerIndex = 0; healthContainerIndex < healthContainers.Length; healthContainerIndex++)
    {
        healthContainers[healthContainerIndex].fillAmount = Mathf.Clamp01((float)currentHealth / healthPerHealthContainer - healthContainerIndex);
    }
}
```